# The import javax.ejb cannot be resolved. How to fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am completely new to Eclipse and need to create an MDB. Do I need to install something else to fix this? I have only installed Eclipse and JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today, just install the [JAR file](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api) and implement it into your Build Path.

Since you are new to eclipse the way to implement a JAR file is by right clicking the project and click on properties. Then go to the Java Build Path and just "Add External JARs", if you can't immediately do this, then click on Modlepath and then just "Add External JARs"